# Join two select queries written for two different tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have two queries.

Example:

```
query1 = session.query(Table1.name, Table1.age, Table1.address, Table1.id)
query2 = session.query(Table2.salary, Table2.abc, Table2.id)
```

I am getting these queries as return values from two different python methods.

I need to join these two queries and get only 'name' from first table and 'salary' from second table based on 'id' column.

SQLALchemy version - 1.3.19

Comment: What SQLALchemy version do you use?

Comment: Updated the question with the version.